# Как отправить post-запрос сервлету через javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, post, servlet

Пишу веб-сервис интересует следующий сценарий.

1. Есть html файлик с таблицей и кнопкой.
2. При выборе поля в таблице полю присваивается новый класс "active"
3. Нажимаю на кнопку
4. желаю в сервлете получить данные, которые находятся в первом столбце выбранного поля.

Вопрос, как организовать post-запрос сервлету через js и отправить данные?

Вот если мы берем из формы данные, то все получается корректно.

А хотелось бы не прибегать к использованию формы, а чтоб по всему Html файлику скрипт пробежался нашел нужные данные и отправил.

Файл скрипта:

```
function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function httpReq(URL, method, data, success, error) {
    var request = getXmlHttp();
    request.open(method, URL, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                success(request.responseText);
            }
            else {
                if (error) error(request.status);
            }
        }
    }
}


var table = document.querySelector("#selectTable")
var field = table.querySelector(".active");
var item = field.children[0];  // первый дочерний

var form = new FormData();
form.append("some_key",
        item.innerHTML);  // ну или что там нужно вытащить
httpReq("/admin", "POST", form, function(res) {
    console.log("response:", res);
});
```

Comment: Советую посмотреть документацию к `getElementById` и `querySelector` - а еще лучше воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function httpReq(URL, method, data, success, error) {
    var request = getXmlHttp();
    request.open(method, URL, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                success(request.responseText);
            }
            else {
                if (error) error(request.status);
            }
        }
    }
}


someBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    var table = document.querySelector("селектор таблицы")
    var field = table.querySelector(".active");
    var item = field.children[0];  // первый дочерний

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("some_key",
            item.innerHTML);  // ну или что там нужно вытащить
    form.append("another_key", another_value);

    httpReq("url...", "POST", form, function(res) {
        console.log("response:", res);
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    })
};
```

Comment: на `readyState` и `status` ругается что-то(

Comment: "ругается что-то" понятие растяжимое. Я не экстрасенс.

Comment: admin:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null

Comment: Функция httpReq без изменений? Покажи файл скрипта, чтоб был виден контекст.

Comment: обновил описание

Comment: А, я мудак, убери там строку request = null;

Comment: теперь без ошибки) 
Сейчас попробую запрос получить и скажу о результате)

Comment: Полностью помогло реализовать все мои старания)) спасибо большое))